# Is CacheBleed fixed in LibreSSL?

Tags: openssl, caching

https://ts.data61.csiro.au/projects/TS/cachebleed/

Only thing I can find: http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20160301141941

**Q:** was CacheBleed fixed in LibreSSL?

Answer (score 1):

## CacheBleed fixed in LibreSSL 2.5.0

- Added constant-time updates to address CVE-2016-0702

And [that CVE-ID is CacheBleed](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-0702).

Source: [OpenBSD "Announce" Mailing list post from 2016-09-28](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-announce&m=147502086132202) (Archived [here](https://archive.fo/mp0S5#selection-59.2745-59.2758).)

Answer (score 0):

On the fly, I've been able to find this quote:

> The developers of LibreSSL are working on a fix but do not have a
>   timeline yet. We have disclosed these results to the developers of the
>   NSS library in early January. We do not know when a fix will be
>   deployed.

However, it's good to ask the LibreSSL team again(s that articleis old), and also notify to this site/article author, to update their article.
[source](https://ts.data61.csiro.au/projects/TS/cachebleed/) (see Q4)